# Error while try getting spark connection id in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, spark-submit

My `SparkSubmitOperator` in airflow  DAG looks as below, below is my `connection_id 'spark_local'` in Airflow UI as [image: Apache Spark Connection] when I try running my DAG am getting this error [image: Airflow error], can anyone please help me if am missing anything here?

`SparkSubmitOperator (task_id='spark_task', application = 'gs://xxx/xxx.jar', conf = {"spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts":True, "spark.blacklist.enabled":False}, conn_id='spark_local', java_class = 'xxx', jars=["gs://xxx/*"], application_args=["xxx "xxx" "xxx,] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `TypeError` , from the documentation https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator/index.html, it said that `jars` argument should be a string. Could you try `jars="gs://xxx/*"` as a string instead to see if it's working?